# You need to configure Two-Factor Authorization in order to proceed

Tags: magento2.4

Having just installed 2.4.0 from scratch, I ran into an "issue" when logging into Magento Backend for the first time:

[image]

> Failed to send the message. Please contact the administrator
> You need to configure Two-Factor Authorization in order to proceed to your store's admin area
> An E-mail was sent to you with further instructions

This implies, that I won't be able to log into Magento without first setting up SMTP on the server. Is there something I'm overlooking that allows me to set this up via the CLI? Therefore, not requiring SMTP to complete the 2FA login.

### Edit 1/2

Having slapped the ability for SMTP onto my test server, I got to see what the email was that it was trying to send:

> You are required to configure personal Two-Factor Authorization in order to login to Main Website Store
> To do that please Click here

Clicking the link displayed the following

[image]

So, I'm starting to think that an SMTP enabled server should be considered a "prerequisite" for installing Magento. However, I'd prefer to see if anyone has another solution (that doesn't involve disabling 2fA).

### Edit 2/2

I ended up reporting this as an [issue with Magento](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29312). Having 2FA enabled by default was put in place as a security feature. Therefore, having to disable it to make Magento accessible makes that decision absolutely pointless. And yes, I could install SMTP facilities on my server but that seems overkill to send a single email.

Comment: Setting up 2FA needs to be part of the 2.4 installation docs.. This is crazy.

Answer (score 86):

For quick access, I recommend disabling the **Magento TwoFactorAuth** module.

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but that totally defeats the point of enforcing 2FA on installation.

Comment: In my case, I use sudo before the command and working for me. 

sudo php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth

Comment: I tried to run this command and it says: -bash: bin/magento: Permission denied Why would that be and what do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: I tried to disable this module but still not working

Comment: Installing Magento locally or in dev server, two factor auth is useless imo

Comment: php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth

Answer (score 13):

please follow the below steps :

1.Select Google Authenticator as the 2FA provider:

```
php bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/general/force_providers google
```

2.Increase the lifetime of the window to 60 seconds to prevent tokens from expiring

```
php bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/google/otp_window 60
```

3.Use the following key to add the encoded value to the MFTF .credentials file:

```
magento/tfa/OTP_SHARED_SECRET=Google_Your_secret_key
```

4. Add the encoded shared secret to Google Authenticator

```
php bin/magento security:tfa:google:set-secret admin Google_Your_secret_key
```

please check this link for more [references](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/security/two-factor-authentication.html).[image]

Admin => https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft9qQ.png

Thank You.

Comment: I read this, but there is a lack of elaboration of Step 3. ("encoded value to the MFTF `.credentials` file"). i.e. guidelines to generating the `Secret Key` and the location of the `.credentials` file.

Comment: Credentials: https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/credentials.html

Answer (score 5):

Buddy I also face the same issue after open admin webpage. You can try to disable 2 Factor Authentication module for first time login using below code in Magento root directory.

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

I know it's not a foolproof step but you can try to login into admin page.

Comment: Working around the problem isn't an issue. It's just the logic of requiring more prerequisites to support an oversight.

Comment: I tried to run this command and it says: -bash: bin/magento: Permission denied

Comment: `
Unable to change status of modules because of the following constraints:
Cannot disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth because modules depend on it:
Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth: Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth->Magento_TwoFactorAuth
`

Answer (score 4):

I found a way, by adding a system configuration to Enable/Disable it. I made a module, you can download it with composer:

```
composer require wolfsellers/module-enabledisabletfa
```

Or check it at: https://github.com/wolfsellers/module-enabledisabletfa

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! Worked like a charm to allow me to install via composer locally and then enable it in Staging where SMTP is functional and the intended way to setup 2FA could be followed.

Answer (score 4):

To disable Two Factor Authentication on localhost/dev server.

Execute the `php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth` command.

or,

Open `app/etc/config.php` and change value for `'Magento_TwoFactorAuth'` to `0`.

Now execute `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command to compile your project.

**N:B:** You may need to prefix `sudo` with above commands depending the files and folder permission in your system.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full answer with some additional details based on Nikunj Rawat answer. Sorry if this is wrong but if you know what you're doing there is no excuse for not giving full and complete answers.

Disabling doesn't help because as soon as your turn it on your stuck in the same position and unless you have SMTP setup this solution is the only sensible one that works. Tested in Magento 2.4.4 (May 18th 2022)

please follow the below steps :

1.Select Google Authenticator as the 2FA provider:

```
php bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/general/force_providers google
```

2.Increase the lifetime of the window to 60 seconds to prevent tokens from expiring

```
php bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/google/otp_window 60
```

3.Create a key (mine is URB4NW4RF4R3 for this example). Use that key in a [tool like this](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base32_encode.html) to generated your base32 encoded shared secret:

```
URB4NW4RF4R3 // your shared secret
```

[image: Screenshot of converting a shared secret into a base32 encoded string]

This your secret key you can now enter this into a file called *.credentials* located in your **/magento_document_root/dev/tests/acceptance/**

```
magento/tfa/OTP_SHARED_SECRET=KVJEENCOK42FERRUKIZQ====
```

4. Add the encoded shared secret to Google Authenticator.
   Open the App > click Add and select > Enter a setup key.
   Give an account name (domain and user) and then enter your Base32 encoded secret into the key field.
5. Set the secret key against your user account.

```
php bin/magento security:tfa:google:set-secret admin KVJEENCOK42FERRUKIZQ====
```

6. You should now be presented with this screen once you login to your account.

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2.4 add some more modules for Two-factor authorization.

Run this command

```
php bin/magento mod:dis Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

Now  Please run the '`setup:di:compile`' command to generate classes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

$ bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth

And

$ php bin/magento c:c

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following module to enable/disable Two Factor Authentication on local, dev, or staging environments as you please using admin configuration.

https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve the issue by combining the solutions above also solved the permissions denied issue.

1. php bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/general/force_providers google
2. php bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/google/otp_window 60
3. sudo php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth

This is what the end result is:

The following modules have been disabled:

- Magento_TwoFactorAuth

Cache cleared successfully.
Generated classes cleared successfully. Please run the 'setup:di:compile' command to generate classes.
Info: Some modules might require static view files to be cleared. To do this, run 'module:disable' with the --clear-static-content option to clear them.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this chrome authenticator extension -

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/authenticator/bhghoamapcdpbohphigoooaddinpkbai?hl=en

Scan the QR code with this extension it will decode the code & provide you six digit 2 factor authentication code use this code & it will re-direct you to admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip it by commenting out if you get this error while running the following CLI command:

```
vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests
```

Open dev\tests\acceptance\ .credentials and comment out OTP_SHARED_SECRET as below:

```
#magento/tfa/OTP_SHARED_SECRET
```