# An E-mail was sent to you with further instructions but still not receiving it...!

Tags: magento2.2.4

I am new with MAGENTO 2.4.0 i have already installed BUT When i try to log in my backend it shows me:

"You need to configure Two-Factor Authorization in order to proceed to your store's admin area
An E-mail was sent to you with further instructions"

i have 4 hours and still not receiving any email in my inbox..

PLEASE, let me know How Can I Solve this....????

best regards

Julio Cesar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You need to configure Two-Factor Authorization in order to proceed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318485/you-need-to-configure-two-factor-authorization-in-order-to-proceed)

Comment: Please take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318715/how-to-disable-two-factor-authentication-module-in-magento-2-4